# How to foreach a database record in MVC C#

Tags: c#, mysql, linq, foreach

I have this C# and linq to database to get all rows of data from database

```
var getOldAttachment = _context.ca_Attachments.Where(x => x.CaseId == getCase[0].Id && x.isDeleted == false).ToList();
```

Than I want to use a foreach to re-insert the exact row of data into database with updates of new datacolumn, in simple words is just to duplicate the same data row but with different values. the data row contains **Id, creator, attachmentid, lastupdateon**. with values of :  **1, tester, 12345,2015-11-16 11:49:50.810 respectively** i just want to change the value of editor to current use which call editor. What am i suppose to put in the ???? portion?

```
if (getOldAttachment != null && getOldAttachment.Count > 0)
                {
                    //foreach (??????)
                    //{
                    //    data.ca_Attachments.Add(new ca_Attachment
                    //    {
                    //        AttachmentId = getOldAttachment.attachmentId,
                    //        creator = editor,
                    //        LastUpdatedOn = _startTime,
                    //    });
                    //}
                }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A note: You don't need to check for `null` after `ToList()`. It will never be null. You also don't need to check for `Count > 0`, since we're going to iterate it (and it will not execute if there are no items anyway).

You can simply write:

```
var oldAttachments = _context.ca_Attachments
                             .Where(x => x.CaseId == getCase[0].Id && !x.isDeleted)
                             .ToList();

foreach (var oldAttachment in oldAttachments) 
{
    data.ca_Attachments.Add(new ca_Attachment
    {
        AttachmentId = oldAttachment.attachmentId,
        creator = editor,
        LastUpdatedOn = _startTime,
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one option using `ForEach`:

```
getOldAttachment.ForEach(att => {
    _context.ca_Attachments.Add(new ca_Attachment
           {
                AttachmentId = att.attachmentId,
                creator = editor,
                LastUpdatedOn = _startTime,
           });
});
```

This uses `_context` to add a new attachment instead of `data` -- not sure what `data` is...

Comment: Not trying to be *that guy*, but `List.ForEach` is not LINQ

Comment: @Jonesopolis -- ah, thanks -- I thought you had to add a reference to `System.Linq` in order to access the `ForEach()` method.

Comment: It sure seems like it, but it's just a method on `List` itself

Comment: @Jonesopolis -- you are absolutely correct -- edited and thanks again: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwabdf9z(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
if (getOldAttachment != null && getOldAttachment.Count > 0)
            {
              for(var i = 0; i < getOldAttachment.Count; i++)
              {
                  //this is how to populate the data from list
                  //sample only
                  ca_Attachment.AttachmentId = getOldAttachment[i].AttachmentId;
                  //do the insert code
              }
            }
```